# dspace error blank xmlui page

Tags: java, dspace, apache-cocoon

I have installed dspace from source on my Ubuntu 16.04 computer.  I followed the steps in the long description here:

https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/Installing+DSpace

When I try to access the xmlui page, I get a white screen in the browser, and a long list of error messages in the log, below.  I have checked, and in the src directory, Context.java has the method getCurrentMode, which is being called by CommunityBrowser.java on line 150.  I get a nice page when I go to jspui, but this same error appears when I have logged in, although it shows an error message on the page rather than nothing at all, as with xmlui.

Can anyone suggest something?

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:238)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.dspace.app.webui.filter.RegisteredOnlyFilter.doFilter(RegisteredOnlyFilter.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.dspace.utils.servlet.DSpaceWebappServletFilter.doFilter(DSpaceWebappServletFilter.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.dspace.core.Context.getCurrentMode()Lorg/dspace/core/Context$Mode;
    at org.dspace.app.xmlui.aspect.artifactbrowser.CommunityBrowser.getValidity(CommunityBrowser.java:150)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor128.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cocoon.core.container.spring.avalon.PoolableProxyHandler.invoke(PoolableProxyHandler.java:71)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy402.getValidity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.impl.AbstractCachingProcessingPipeline.getValidityForInternalPipeline(AbstractCachingProcessingPipeline.java:987)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.impl.AbstractCachingProcessingPipeline.setupValidities(AbstractCachingProcessingPipeline.java:482)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.impl.AbstractCachingProcessingPipeline.setupPipeline(AbstractCachingProcessingPipeline.java:720)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.preparePipeline(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:466)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.prepareInternal(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:480)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor127.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cocoon.core.container.spring.avalon.PoolableProxyHandler.invoke(PoolableProxyHandler.java:71)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy396.prepareInternal(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSource.init(SitemapSource.java:292)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSource.<init>(SitemapSource.java:148)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSourceFactory.getSource(SitemapSourceFactory.java:62)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.CocoonSourceResolver.resolveURI(CocoonSourceResolver.java:153)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.CocoonSourceResolver.resolveURI(CocoonSourceResolver.java:183)
    at org.apache.cocoon.generation.FileGenerator.setup(FileGenerator.java:99)
    at org.dspace.app.xmlui.cocoon.AspectGenerator.setup(AspectGenerator.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor118.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cocoon.core.container.spring.avalon.PoolableProxyHandler.invoke(PoolableProxyHandler.java:71)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy397.setup(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.setupPipeline(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:343)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.impl.AbstractCachingProcessingPipeline.setupPipeline(AbstractCachingProcessingPipeline.java:710)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.preparePipeline(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:466)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.prepareInternal(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:480)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor127.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cocoon.core.container.spring.avalon.PoolableProxyHandler.invoke(PoolableProxyHandler.java:71)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy396.prepareInternal(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSource.init(SitemapSource.java:292)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSource.<init>(SitemapSource.java:148)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSourceFactory.getSource(SitemapSourceFactory.java:62)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.CocoonSourceResolver.resolveURI(CocoonSourceResolver.java:153)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.CocoonSourceResolver.resolveURI(CocoonSourceResolver.java:183)
    at org.apache.cocoon.generation.FileGenerator.setup(FileGenerator.java:99)
    at org.dspace.app.xmlui.cocoon.AspectGenerator.setup(AspectGenerator.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor118.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cocoon.core.container.spring.avalon.PoolableProxyHandler.invoke(PoolableProxyHandler.java:71)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy397.setup(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.setupPipeline(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:343)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.impl.AbstractCachingProcessingPipeline.setupPipeline(AbstractCachingProcessingPipeline.java:710)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.preparePipeline(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:466)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.prepareInternal(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:480)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cocoon.core.container.spring.avalon.PoolableProxyHandler.invoke(PoolableProxyHandler.java:71)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy396.prepareInternal(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSource.init(SitemapSource.java:292)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSource.<init>(SitemapSource.java:148)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSourceFactory.getSource(SitemapSourceFactory.java:62)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.CocoonSourceResolver.resolveURI(CocoonSourceResolver.java:153)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.CocoonSourceResolver.resolveURI(CocoonSourceResolver.java:183)
    at org.apache.cocoon.generation.FileGenerator.setup(FileGenerator.java:99)
```

and many more cocoon errors...

Comment: Mostly the reason of `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` are incompatible jar files

Comment: Thanks, @Jens!  I am checking this.

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally, on that first day, I made a couple of mistakes in the installation process.  For instance, I failed to set my database password in the dspace.cfg or the local.cfg the first time.  I set the password, and then tried again without deleting everything first.  I assumed it would overwrite and correct anything that was wrong.

So after @Jens suggestion, I thought that trying to find conflicting jar files would be quite difficult with an install that used as many jar files as dspace does. So I tried again the next day from scratch.  I downloaded a new file, I deleted my database and all dspace files from the file system.  I started and, having learned from my mistakes, I went through the install steps without the mistakes, and in the end everything worked.  I now have a source code install that I can modify.

Thanks again to @Jens for the pointer.